# Overflow CSS not working with firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a weird issue.

```
Overflow : hidden
```

is not correctly working with Firefox 41 (i've also tried on 40 and 39).

Scrolling is disabled with the scroll ball and there's no scroll bar on the right, but I still can scroll down using the keyboards arrows.

On IE Chrome Opera and Safari everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve it by combining the overflow with a fixed position.
And when I did that it affects the width also so (i don't really know why also)

```
.test {
overflow-y: hidden;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

But I still dont understand why this happend

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running into https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=261037, which is fixed in the upcoming Firefox 28. That's shipping about 5 days from now, so unless you really need this working in old Firefox versions I wouldn't bother with workarounds; just assume it will work.

If you do need to work around, you can try using a nested div inside the fieldset, with height set to 100% and the overflow style on the div.